# Can two fermions occupy the same energy level on a harmonic potential?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator, fermions, pauli-exclusion-principle, identical-particles

Suppose that we have a harmonic potential $\hat{V}(\hat{X})=\frac{1}{2}k\hat{X}^2$ which we will, for simplicity, consider to be one dimensional. Now let's place two fermions within this potential, then the total hamiltonian would be:

$$
\hat{H}(1,2)=\frac{\hat{P_1}^2}{2m}+\frac{1}{2}k\hat{X_1}^2+\frac{\hat{P_2}^2}{2m}+\frac{1}{2}k\hat{X_2}^2
$$

which in the diagonal basis could be written:

$$
\hat{H}(1,2)=\hbar\omega(\hat{N}_{1x}+\hat{N}_{2x}+1)
$$

where $\hat{N}$ is the number operator. For the ground state we know that the wavefunction for a single particles is:

$$
\psi_0(x_i)=\bigg(\frac{\beta^2}{\pi}\bigg)e^{\frac{\beta^2 x_i^2}{2}}
$$

Thus, as the solution to the Shrodinger equation is separable, then the solutions for the two particle problem would simply be $\psi_{00}(x_1,x_2)=\psi_0(x_1)\psi_0(x_2)$. Now there are several several things I don't understand:

1. By accepting that the wavefunction of fermions has to be antisymmetric under permutation I see easily that the resulting wave function has to be $\psi_{00}(x_1,x_2)=1/\sqrt{2}(\psi_0(x_1)\psi_0(x_2)-\psi_0(x_2)\psi_0(x_1))$. But what if I had no idea that I had two fermions? What if I had a boson and a fermion?
2. Recognizing that we have two spin 1/2 particles that we have to account for their spin, then the resulting quantum state would need to be described by 6 quantum numbers in the basis $\{|n_1,s_1,m_{s_1}\rangle \otimes |n_2,s_2,m_{s_2}\rangle \}$, or we could change to the coupled basis and have $\{n_1,n_2,S,M\rangle \}$.By knowing that the coupled basis is (in terms of the $\{|\pm,\pm\rangle\}$ basis):

$$
|11\rangle=|++\rangle \\
|10\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|+-\rangle+|-+\rangle \\
|01\rangle=|--\rangle \\
|00\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|+-\rangle-|-+\rangle \\
$$

then in order to fully characterize my quantum state I need 4 quantum numbers, which only 2 give any information about the energy. From the basis above only the singlet state ($|00\rangle$) is antisymmetric under permutation. However the wavefunction is independent of the spin, so while I keep my wavefunction as stated in 1, would I have 4 quantum states associated to it even though the electrons could occupy the same quantum state at the same time with the states $|0011\rangle$ and $|001-1\rangle$ be forbidden?

Comment: Please try to restrict the number of questions per post. Though they are connected, it does not help you get answers.